# Making a chrome extension using Perl

Tags: perl, google-chrome-extension

I am new to this and I followed [official tutorial](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html).

I made a folder in my desktop named as `Chrome` and put all files `manifest.json`, `popup.html`, `icon.png` there along with a file `guestbook.pl`. Now the content of `manifest.json` is same as given in above link but I changed the code of `popup.html` according to my need which is:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Guestbook</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/home/chankey/Desktop/Chrome/guestbook.pl" method="get">
<table>
<tr><td>Name</td><td><input name="name" type="text" value=""></td></tr>
<tr><td>E-Mail</td><td><input name="email" type="text" value=""></td></tr>
<tr><td>Location</td><td><input name="loc" type="text" value=""></td></tr>
<tr><td>Comments</td><td>
<TEXTAREA name="comments" rows="10" cols="32"></TEXTAREA></td></tr>
</table><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Add Entry">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Then I added the extension on my Google Chrome. Extension added successfully and when I click on it a form appears (from `popup.html`) but when I click on "Add Entry" button to submit the data the script (`guestbook.pl`) doesn't run. A new page appears which says

> This web page has not been found, No web page was found for the web address: chrome-extension://plkeijfkmjeakkbdclipkoadchbpgpdm/home/chankey/Desktop/Chrome/guestbook.pl?name=&email=&loc=&comments=

Why is this happening? The script is in the same directory then why isn't chrome finding it?

---

### guestbook.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $query_string = "";
#Get the input
if ($ENV{REQUEST_METHOD} eq 'POST') {
read(STDIN, $query_string, $ENV{CONTENT_LENGTH});
} else {
$query_string = $ENV{QUERY_STRING};
}
##### We will remove this
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
print "Query String is \n<br> $query_string";
print "hi";
##### We will remove this
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't run Perl in Chrome.  Chrome extensions are small web pages and can only use client-side web technologies.  Therefore, the language you use is JavaScript.

To create a guestbook style extension you'd have to run your guestbook.pl script on a web server and then use AJAX calls from JavaScript in the extension to save and get the data.